# How to get bean property value in JavaScript without using hidden tags in XHTML?

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces, portlet

I pass the values to managedbean using JSON and remotecommand but when I try to see the managed bean's value in JavaScript I see the default value not the updated value.

I do not want to refresh the page or use hidden tags in XHTML as I might need much data exchange.

When the value changed:

```
<script>
    var json= [ { name : 'zoom',  value : zoomLevel }  ];          
    sendParams(json);
</script>
```

in my .js file I use remotecommand:

```
function sendParams(jsonData) { 
    passToJSFManagedBean (jsonData);  
}
```

in .xhtml I call the function in the managedbean:

```
<p:remoteCommand name="passToJSFManagedBean" id="passToJSFManagedBeancmd" action="#{tagBean.setParams}" process="@this" />
```

in managed bean:

```
public void setParams() {
   this.zoom= Integer.parseInt(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("zoom")); 
   System.out.println("Zoom level: "+zoom); 
}
```

Then we could see the value passed managed bean. But when I try in js the zoom value is not updated and has the default value.

```
alert('#{tagBean.zoom}');
```

Is there any way to get managed bean's properties in javascript without using hidden tags in xhtml ? Important is that the Page dose not need to refresh. Is it possible to use remotecommand to get managedbean values? Thanks for help.

Comment: *"But when I try in js the zoom value is not updated and has the default value."* Just `update` the zoom value in client side then?

Comment: I think it is a workaround. I wonder what the reason is.

Comment: I know but I dont want to print on the page or use hidden tags in xhtml page. I use openlayers & leafletjs and get some value from them like zoom value. And I need other values to exchange data between managedbean and js. So using #{} for each property in xhtml is workload. Where I am wrong? Please help me to correct my wrong.

Comment: when I change the zoom value on the map I update the zoom value via the function in js that calls remoteCommand and it updates the zoom value in managed bean. After the value updated, to get the updated value in js I use primefaces' requestContext that calls getZoom value in managed bean and transform it to the function in js. But I see the zoom value still has default value not the updated value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In primefaces, via requestContext I can get the bean's property.

Comment: But there is still problem. I get the default bean property value not the updated bean property value. Is it the reason that I update the value with a remotecommand that calls setParam function in managed bean ?